# Make an iteration more functional in JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I wrote a simple bit of JavaScript to create a HTML table.
It is populated by iterating over an array

```
var resultSet;
for (var i = 0, i < questions.length;; i++){ 
   ...
    resultSet += '<tr>' + '<td>' + i + '</td><td>' + questions[i].question + '</td><td>' + questions[i].userAnswer + '</td><td>' +
questions[i].correctAnswer + '</td>' + '</tr>';
}
```

So this an imperative approach.  I was reading about Scala where an example to something similar would be:

```
questions.map(n => '<tr>' + '<td>' + '</td><td>' + questions[i].question  + ...);
```

Which is a functional. The emphasis being on the what rather than the how.

So I am wondering how to make my JavaScript more functional?

Use of JQuery of course permitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) however with limited compatibility: While all other browsers support it, IE only supports it from IE9 on - so you might need a shim for the other IEs.

Basically you could write:

```
questions.forEach(function(a){
resultSet += '<tr><td>' + a.question + '</td><td>' + 
             a.userAnswer + '</td><td>' +
             a.correctAnswer + '</td></tr>';
});
```

jQuery provides [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) which gives you the same functionality:

```
$.each(questions, function(index, value) {
  /* Do your stuff*/
});
```

Comment: Does JQuery support something very similar which make allowances for all IE?

Answer (score 2):

First, correct Scala will be

```
questions.map(q => '<tr>' + '<td>' + '</td><td>' + q.question  + ...);
```

where `q` is an element of `questions`, not an index.

JavaScript also has [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (see Browser Compatibility at the end for browsers which support this method). So it's the same:

```
questions.map(function(q) { 
  return '<tr>' + '<td>' + '</td><td>' + q.question + ... 
});
```

Comment: Javascripts `map` is for mapping one array to another, not for the purpose the OP wants. Also beware the Compatibility.

Comment: @Christoph Same in Scala, so I assumed `resultSet` was an array.